# printing array lengthwise: java

Tags: java, arrays, methods, printing

This is my code.

```
public void print()
    {
        String x = " ";
        System.out.println("------------");
        for (int iteration = 0 ; iteration < array1.length; iteration ++)
        {
            System.out.println("|" +(array1[iteration]) + "|" );

        }
        System.out.println("------------");

    }
```

It prints like this

```
(-----------------)-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|3|(-----------------)-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|3|(-----------------)-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|3|(-----------------)-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|3|(-----------------)-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|3|(-----------------)-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|3|(-----------------)-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|3|(-----------------)-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|3|
```

I want it to print like this `|3||3||3||3||3||3||3||3||3||3|`. How is this possible?> Thanks.

Comment: `System.out.print("|" +(array1[iteration]) + "|" );`

Comment: AH!!! I keep forgetting how to do that! Thanks! I feel so dumb. :D

Answer (score 0):

Remove the lines where you print `----...`. thats it, you can add that in the caller method if you want a wrapper to the expected output.

```
  public void print()
    {
        String x = " ";
        for (int iteration = 0 ; iteration < array1.length; iteration ++)
        {
            System.out.println("|" +(array1[iteration]) + "|" );

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, what you guys think?> It works perfectly inside the method.

```
public void print()
    {
        String x = "---";
        for (int iteration = 0 ; iteration < array1.length; iteration ++)
        {
            System.out.print(x);

        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int iteration = 0 ; iteration < array1.length; iteration ++)
        {
            System.out.print("|" +(array1[iteration]) );

        }
        System.out.print("|");
        System.out.println();
        for (int iteration = 0 ; iteration < array1.length; iteration ++)
        {
            System.out.print(x);

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```